# Get a result of a log file parsing speed every 10 seconds in python

Tags: python

I have a python code to parse a 1 TB log file, but the problem is my result is shown after the parsing process is finished. So for that I need to wait for 12 hours, and after 12 hours only then the result is shown. I want to know how can I parse a log file and know the result of the parsing speed every 10 seconds. 
This is my code:

```
import re
import timeit
log_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/ip.txt'
output_file ='/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/k2u.csv'
name_to_check = 'MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'
class Log_minning:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def get_userdata(self):
        user_att = []
        list_usr = []
        counterr = 0
        with open(log_file, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if name_to_check in line:
                    username = re.search(r'(?<=userName=)(.*)(?=,)', line)
                    username = username.group()
                    date = re.search(r"([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])+"
                                     "(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))", line)
                    date = date.group()
                    time = re.search(r"(\d{9}\+\d{4})", line)
                    time = time.group()
                    ip = re.search(
                        r'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.)'
                        '{3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])',
                        line
                    )
                    ip = ip.group()
                    user_att.append(username)
                    user_att.append(date)
                    user_att.append(time)
                    user_att.append(ip)
                    list_usr.append(user_att)
                    counterr = counterr + 1
        self.counter = counterr
        return list_usr
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lm = Log_minning()
    the_time = timeit.Timer(lm.get_userdata).repeat(1, 1000)
    sing_time = min(the_time)/1000
    speed = 600 / sing_time * lm.counter
    # for line in lm.get_userdata():
    #     print(line)
    print(
            "Processing " + str(lm.counter) + " in " + str(the_time) +
            "\nThe speed aproximately " + str(speed) + " data in 10 sec"
        )
```

This is the fully scanned seconds

```
Processing 117 in [6.646515152002394]
```

Comment: You are calling `re.search` 4 times for each line. Regexes are slow. If you do all of it in one search, the process will take 3 hours instead of 12. If you don't use regex at all, it might fall to several minutes.

Comment: Check out tqdm, a progress bar module. There's a good description of how to use it with files [here](https://blog.nelsonliu.me/2016/07/29/progress-bars-for-python-file-reading-with-tqdm/).